# What are the ways to get more local storage space (than standard 5M limit or so) for your HTML5 app?

Tags: html

The web is full of contradictory pointers to browser specificity details on the above matter and this is why I'd prefer to get some expert advice. Currently I don't care about non webkit browsers. But the more I study the subject, the more confirmations, that it is currently rather impossible, I find. So, I'd be grateful for any insights, tips or whatsoever. Also I wonder about how things may change with flow of time. Thanks.

Comment: 5 megs should be enough for anyone...

Comment: @op, see tagawas answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567509/what-happens-when-localstorage-is-full

Answer (score 1):

A [section in the draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#user-tracking) says the following about raising the localStorage limit:

> **Site-specific white-listing of access to local storage areas User**
>   agents may allow sites to access session storage areas in an
>   unrestricted manner, but require the user to authorize access to local
>   storage areas.
>   -- http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#user-tracking

I'd recommend you [test for yourself](http://arty.name/localstorage.html) in the browsers you intend to support.

My results in Chromium was a hard limit of ~2600k characters.

EDIT: There's some information on [What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/max-size-of-localstorage-values).

> Actually Opera doesn't have 5MB limit. It offers to increase limit as
>   applications requires more. User can even choose "Unlimited storage"
>   for a domain.

I also found https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-discuss/msg/45153a251b4f441b which states that unlimited storages *is* available for Chromium apps.

Comment: Thank you, joar. I didn't know about unlimitedStorage permission for chrome-apps and this sounds promising to me as I asked my question thinking about building a chrome-app. I'll check later if it really works and then will accept your answer.

Comment: Perhaps the example at https://developers.google.com/chrome/apps/docs/developers_guide#live will make you more confident.

Comment: Although, your answer is correct, @joar, the unlimitedStorage permission is not working with localStorage. See the image: http://s17.postimage.org/d3wqtlsjj/Screenshot.png