# Example Data of localstorage and sessionstorage

Tags: html, local-storage, session-storage

**I understand the textbook definition/concept of localstorage and sessionstorage**.  I really should write, "I believe I do".  My 2 questions are as follows:

1. Can you provide a clear example of when one (localstorage/session storage) should be used over the other?  Basically, what data should
   be stored in the localstorage and what data would be stored in the
   sessionstorage?  I have read a list of country codes could go into the local storage, I ponder if this is really right.  What would happen if the country list changes, wouldn't the old list always display and how would one refresh the list upon a change?
2. What happens when the localstorage and/or sessionstorage hits
   the max mb for the browser?

Comment: 2) they get deleted by the browser subprocesses

Comment: So if the localstorage gets filled, the **entire** localstorage gets deleted by the browser subprocesses?

Comment: it doesnt depend on your website alone

Comment: if the whole space allotted for local and session storage by the browser is exceeded, the browser cleans itself

Comment: could be your website or someone elses

Comment: Ah Ok, thanks.  would like to give you the points, do you know #1 above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The data you store either with LocalStorage or SessionStorage depends on how you want your user to experience your application.

For example, if you have a login page, the username should be something kept with **LocalStorage**, because probably this same user will log into your app multiple times and not necesseraly wants to save the password in the browser. Having the username in LocalStorage will make it easier for the user to login in the future, even after closing the browser or changing tabs.


But, if you have a system that provides services like *booking*, *searching* or maybe *comparison* between products, storing data with **SessionStorage** would be better, because although the values set by the user while using your application won't change during this *session*, they might - and probably will - change in a future use of your application.

In your case specifically, and repeating what was said in the beginning, even with changes in your list of countries, you need to have in mind how your user will interact with your system and what are **your needs** with the data that is being provided by them.

Don't forget you can always clean the localStorage if you need, and set new values as they appear.

2) There's a really good explanation of how the browser responds to a full memory [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567509/what-happens-when-localstorage-is-full)